# Preload a bunch of images from an array of file names, do function after 50% are done

Tags: javascript, function, preload

Hay, i'm using this script

```
function preloader(images){
         var i = 0;
         imageObj = new Image();


         // start preloading
         for(i=0; i<=images.length; i++){
            imageObj.src=images[i];
            imageObj.onLoad = check(i, images.length / 2);
         };

    }
```

and passing a bunch of images into it to preload.

the check() function is this

```
check = function(e,i){
        if( e == i ){
             run_fading_gallery(imgcode);
            $(".loading").hide();
        };
    }
```

But it doesnt seem to be working.

Any ideas? Or is there anything i can use online already?

Comment: Remember to mark an answer as accepted if it works, or comment if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you set only 1 imageObj and changing its source and event handler. Why don't you try creating an image object for each image? (in your loop).

To be more specific:

```
function preloader(images){
         var i = 0;

         // start preloading
         for(i=0; i<=images.length; i++){
            imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src=images[i];
            imageObj.onLoad = check(i, images.length / 2);
         };

    }
```

Comment: What's the difference, when you rewrite the imageObj anyway?

Comment: If you modify the same object, the browser will stop loading the previously set src. Also, you'll only get a load event for the last image, which isn't what you want. Also, it should be .onload, not .onLoad.

Answer (score 0):

`images.length / 2` will not be a whole number if there are an odd number of images in the array, hence it will never be equal to `i` in the check function. Try `Math.floor`:

```
function preloader(images){
     var i = 0;
     imageObj = new Image();


     // start preloading
     for(i=0; i<=images.length; i++){

        imageObj.onLoad = check(i, Math.floor(images.length / 2));
        imageObj.src=images[i];
     };

}
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with imageObj.onLoad(). The function doesn't seem to be called once the image has been loaded, but once the image has been requested. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, perhaps add the event before you set the `src` - I've edited my code to show this now.

Comment: I don't understand that comment. In your question you said you wanted to perform an action after 50 percent were loaded?

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. Suppose you have a 100 images.
Images load asynchronously. If the first image loaded is image number 50, then the function will say 50 images have been loaded, while only 1 image is loaded.